# How to draw Polylines in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I would like to know how to draw and connect lines or polylines in JavaFX.
My code accuses error that within events I can not use scene, nor root nor any of these variables would I give the output of the polyline. Can anyone help me or post a code using these data structures that I used (so it will not get so confusing)?

Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);

        double x=0.0,y=0.0;
        EventHandler filter = new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(InputEvent event) {
                     Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(0.0f);
        line.setStartY(0.0f);
        line.setEndX(100.0f);
        line.setEndY(100.0f);
        box.getChildren().add(line);


            }
        };
// Register the same filter for two different nodes
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, filter);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

What I wanted is actually within the event, to be able to show each Poliline state.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm having a problem with modeling, I'd like to go by making the lines connecting them. In this line:
         Box.getChildren (). Add (line);

I can not go adding to the box for each time the event runs? I'm not understanding how to communicate my box with the Mouse Event

Comment: In the question, you said it gives an error. What is the actual error? When I run the code you posted, I don't see any error (I see the lines, though probably not doing what you want).

Answer (score 1):

This app stores the mouse pointer's location when the mouse is pressed. It then stores the mouse pointer's location when the mouse is released. Next, it takes this info and creates a line and draws that line to the scene.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication134 extends Application
{
    double startX;
    double startY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {       
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        scene.setOnMousePressed((event)->{
            startX = event.getSceneX();
            startY = event.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseReleased((event)->{
            double endX = event.getSceneX();
            double endY = event.getSceneY();

            Line line = new Line();
            line.setStartX(startX);
            line.setStartY(startY);
            line.setEndX(endX);
            line.setEndY(endY);

            root.getChildren().add(line);
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Polyline` class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PolylineDemo extends Application{
    private Polyline polyline;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            polyline = new Polyline();
            root.getChildren().add(polyline);
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            polyline.getPoints().addAll(event.getX(), event.getY());
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: Polyline javaFx demo]